# What does "nearness to" mean in this context?

Tags: word-usage

As I read an article from Bloomberg, I came across this paragraph.

> InvestHK is using a different approach in its sales pitch for entrepreneurs. Instead of talking up the city’s potential for apps like Uber or Yelp, **it’s selling nearness to the world’s factory floor** across the border in China’s Guangdong province. 
>   (http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2016-06-07/hong-kong-without-billion-dollar-unicorn-shows-startup-struggles)

I understand that "nearness" means "being near or close" but I'm not exactly sure what the sentence means with that expression.

Can someone please explain this to me? :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, nearness means "closeness" in this context. It means "being very close to". So I would rephrase the sentence as

> it is selling **closeness** to China’s Guangdong province, which is across the border and is considered to be the world's factory floor.

This implies that there are many factories and factory workers available in the Guangdong province.